# jira-ruby: issue.save returning false

Tags: ruby, jira-rest-api

I am trying to create an issue with jira-ruby in the terminal. So far I have done the following (where username, password, site and project have been replaced with the proper values). I have been able to fetch issues, but not to create them. Jira-ruby return false when i try and save an issue

```
options = {
:username     => "username",
:password     => "password",
:site         => 'site',
:context_path => '',
:auth_type    => :basic
}

client = JIRA::Client.new(options)

issue = client.Issue.build
issue.save({
  "fields" => {
    "summary"   => "blarg from in example.rb",
    "project"   => {"key" => "mykey"},
    "issuetype" => {"id" => "1"}
  }
})

=> false

issue.attrs
=>  {"errorMessages"=>[], "errors"=>{"issuetype"=>"issue type is required"}, "summary"=>"blarg from in example.rb", "key"=>"somekey", "id"=>"someid", "self"=>"site", "exception"=>{"class"=>"Net::HTTPBadRequest", "code"=>"400", "message"=>"Bad Request"}}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: What is the value of `issue.attrs` after your attempt to save? Does it include any error messages?

Comment: I have updated the question to answer your question

Comment: I'm guessing that's a bit of overkill on the info, but I'm not familiar with the `jira-ruby` and didn't find an `errors` method in the documentation, but I guess they redirect it to the internal attributes. So `issue.errors` would be enough. I've noticed that you already added `"issuetype" => {"id" => "1"}` to the `save` call. Is the result you've added ("issue type is required") from the updated `save`, or from the `save` before you updated your `save` request. If from the updated version are you sure the provided issuetype id is valid?

Comment: It works now, thanks a lot. The issues are from the first save, so I think it is all in order now